# Recruitment Suggestions

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I am recruiting for a developer and a database administrator. What is your experience on how to attract top talent for these roles?

Comment: Note to self: Essence Recruitment ask the Internet for help on how to do the one job you ask them to do.

Answer (score 3):

Pay the most, offer the most interesting projects, offer room for employee growth and ownership.